# Build/Compile gst-rstp-server

Tags: build, compilation, gstreamer

I tried to install the GitHub repository(gst-rstp-server)

I have a Ubuntu 16.04, I want to execute the examples in the repository but I don't really know how to build the repository. I haven't found any information about the new releases of gst-rstp-server.

The steps that I took were:

```
./autogen.sh --noconfigure && GST_PLUGINS_GOOD_DIR=$(pkg-config --variable=pluginsdir gstreamer-plugins-bad-1.0) ./configure && make
```

But the shell sends me this exit status:

```
    + configure run disabled
+ check for build tools
  checking for autoreconf ... 
/usr/bin/autoreconf
  checking for pkg-config ... 
/usr/bin/pkg-config
aclocal: warning: couldn't open directory 'm4': No such file or directory
gst/rtsp-server/Makefile.am:54: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
gst/rtsp-server/Makefile.am:54:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
gst/rtsp-server/Makefile.am:54:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
gst/rtsp-server/Makefile.am:54:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
gst/rtsp-server/Makefile.am:54:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
gst/rtsp-sink/Makefile.am:1: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
gst/rtsp-sink/Makefile.am:1:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
gst/rtsp-sink/Makefile.am:1:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
gst/rtsp-sink/Makefile.am:1:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
gst/rtsp-sink/Makefile.am:1:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

If anyone knows how to build the project, it will be very helpful.

```
[Link to the gst-rstp-repository][1]
```

Comment: Why do you want build it yourself? gst-rtsp-server library already included to ubuntu distribution.

Comment: If you still want build it yourself I would recommend you use https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-build

Comment: really? i didnt know that it's already included in ubuntu. I thought that the library included was only the gstream but not the server library. Thanks for both comments.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgstrtspserver-1.0-0&searchon=names